# Как отдельные элементы массива кидать в конец списка?

Tags: javascript

У нас есть массив объектов, в каждом из них есть флаг 'read': {true | false}

Как реализовать сортировку массива так, чтобы объекты с флагом 'read: true' падали в конец списка?

Comment: метод `sort` принимает функцию, с помощью которой можно сортировать

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {  
  if (a.read == b.read)
    return 0;
  else if (a.read)
    return 1;
  else
    return -1;
});
```

или

```
arr.sort((a, b) => (a.read? 1 : -1) - (b.read? 1 : -1));
```

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 1, read: true },
  { id: 2, read: false },
  { id: 3, read: true },
  { id: 4, read: false },
  { id: 5, read: true }
];
arr.sort((a, b) => a.read - b.read);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```